# Posts from a Flash/Flex app is not appearing on my home page News Feed.

Tags: flash, facebook-graph-api

I used the sample tutorial as starting point for an application.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/flex_fbgraph_intro.html

The application logs in fine to my facebook account and is able to display the latest news feed status updates from my account. The problem I have is that when I do a post it is not showing up on my Home Page.

Here is what it does to login:
       Facebook.login(loginHandler,{scope:"user_birthday,read_stream, publish_stream"});

Here is the login handler:

```
protected function loginHandler(success:Object,fail:Object):void
{
if(success){
    loggedIn = true;
    currentState="map";
    Facebook.api("/me",getMeHandler);
    Facebook.api("/me/statuses",getStatusHandler);
}
}
```

Here is what I do to post:

```
 protected function submitPost():void
   {
     Facebook.api("/me/feed",submitPostHandler,{    message:statusInput.text},"POST"); 
   }

   protected function submitPostHandler(result:Object,fail:Object):void
   {
     statusInput.text="";
    Facebook.api("/me/statuses",getStatusHandler);
   }
```

And here are is the status Handler:

```
  protected function getStatusHandler(result:Object, fail:Object):void
   {
     fbUser.status = result[0].message;
   }
```

Thanks in advance!
-Scott

Comment: The function `submitPostHandler()` should get called both on success or failure of the post.  What do you see in the `fail` and `result` objects when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I think only the posts from my facebook account show up in my "Home" News feed not any of the ones I posted from the application. If I click on my name with the profile pick to the left of the "Find Friends" like I see ALL of my posts even from the application.

-Scott